# How to manage the Memory Leaks at the time of access the database?

Tags: iphone

Iam developing one application.In that iam using one array for return the array of values in one function for getting the data from database.And allocate the memory for that one and use the autorelease.But that was killed at the time of execute that line.When iam release that one in dealloc function app will be crashed.If u dont use autorelease and release then memory leaks will be occured.sample for that function is below.

```
-(NSMutableArray*)getWeeklyTableInfo:(int)month:(int)week
  {
     NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM CalendarEvents where   Mont=%d and Week=%d ",month,week];
    sqlite3_stmt *stStatement;
     EventsArray1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [query UTF8String], -1, &stStatement, nil)==SQLITE_OK)
    {
      while (sqlite3_step(stStatement)==SQLITE_ROW) {
            databasefields = [[DataBaseFields alloc]init];
            databasefields.DBSno=sqlite3_column_int(stStatement, 0);
            databasefields.DBdate =[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char*)sqlite3_column_text(stStatement, 1)];
            databasefields.DByear=sqlite3_column_int(stStatement, 2);
            databasefields.DBmonth=sqlite3_column_int(stStatement, 3);
            databasefields.DBweek=sqlite3_column_int(stStatement, 4);
            databasefields.DBtitle = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char*)sqlite3_column_text(stStatement, 5)];
            databasefields.DBlocation = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char*)sqlite3_column_text(stStatement, 6)];
            databasefields.DBtime = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char*)sqlite3_column_text(stStatement, 7)];
            databasefields.DBrepeat=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char*)sqlite3_column_text(stStatement, 8)];
            databasefields.DBalert=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char*)sqlite3_column_text(stStatement, 9)];
            databasefields.DBnotes=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char*)sqlite3_column_text(stStatement, 10)];
            databasefields.DBaudio=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char*)sqlite3_column_text(stStatement, 12)];
            databasefields.DBpicture=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char*)sqlite3_column_text(stStatement, 11)];
            databasefields.DBPhoneNO=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char*)sqlite3_column_text(stStatement, 13)];
            databasefields.DBMailID=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char*)sqlite3_column_text(stStatement, 14)];
            [EventsArray1 addObject:databasefields];
            [databasefields release];
        }
        if (stStatement!= nil) {
            sqlite3_finalize(stStatement);
        }
    }

sqlite3_close(database);
return EventsArray1;
```

}

so please tell me how to do that one.

Answer (score 1):

You are not releasing your EventsArray. You have to autorelease it as follows:

```
EventsArray1 = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
```

You can't simply release it because you are using it on the return.

I think the problem must be that EventsArray is not local to the function. It is a "global" variable. So you should make a new NSMutableArray for use inside the function, then give its values to EventsArray1 and then release the NSMutableArray that you created in the function, then you can return EventsArray safely.

I'm not sure if I understood the question but that is the mistake I see in the example provided.

Comment: But if iam using like this then app will be crashed at this line

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with the following it will work:-

1) Your Method first code line

```
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
```

2) During EventArray1 initialization

```
EventsArray1 = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
```

3) Method Last Line

```
[pool release];
```

Or Second Approach is

Declare a NSMutableArray in .h file named eventArray

then inside function implementation
use

```
EventsArray1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

self.eventArray=EventsArray1

[EventsArray1 release];

return eventArray;
```

Answer (score 0):

As said by Jose, use "autorelease".

But keep in mind while using the array returned by the te method, you should copy into new array. The application will crash if you use the same array, as memory allocated to array was released.

Try using ARC, with new iOS SDK, you will not have to worry about the release, autorelease. ARC will take care of that for you. :)